# How could I display a PDF file in the browser from an input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, pdf, attachment

I want to have an input field in a form using method "post". In the form there will be an attachment field where a user can upload PDF files.

On another page I want the user to be able to view the uploaded pdf file IN the browser using a viewer.

What would be the best way to do this without having the user download/open the PDF file in a separate program?

Thanks!

Comment: The "best way" is a matter of opinion, which is not a good fit for SO. Please specify the objective criteria needed to determine "best", if any. Also, the ability to display PDFs in a browser window as opposed to a separate program is dependent on the browser and the user's setup. For instance, I can set Chrome to always display PDFs in Adobe Acrobat, no matter your wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two real components to this problem: uploading and storing the files and then actually serving them to the user.

**Storing the Files**

As far as actually uploading an saving the PDF files, you can handle posting them to the server using an `<input type='file' />` element :

```
<form action='{your target location}' method='post'>
     <input type='file' name='pdf' />
     <input type='submit' value='Upload PDF File' />
</form>
```

Saving the actual files themselves will vary depending on the server-side technology that you are using. But basically after saving them, you'll want to have some type of mechanism to serve them to the user (either by directly accessing the file or using some other mechanism like a database that is storing their content).

**Viewing the Files**

Most modern browsers have some built-in utility to render PDFs, however if you wanted a solution that is fairly consistent across most browsers and falls back for others, you may consider using [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to handle rendering them within the browser. It offers support for most browsers (with limited support around Internet Explorer 9).

Comment: Thanks Rion! I will probably store the file as a path in a database. I will checkout PDF.js!!